# Spring not creating bean with boolean in the constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a simple bean passing a file and a boolean in the constructor, as follows:

```
@Service
public class FileBasedSink implements Sink {
 protected File outputDirectory;
 protected boolean useCompression;

 public FileBasedSink(File outputDirectory, boolean useCompression) {
    this.outputDirectory = outputDirectory;
    this.useCompression = useCompression;

}


}
```

and the spring-context file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.aksw.simba.squirrel" />

    <!-- 
        <bean id="workerImpl" class="org.aksw.simba.squirrel.worker.impl.WorkerImpl"></bean>
     -->
    <!-- Output folder for FileBasedSink -->
    <bean id="outputFolder" class="java.io.File">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="{systemProperties['OUTPUT_FOLDER']}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- File Based Sink implementation -->
    <bean id="fileSink" class="org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.impl.file.FileBasedSink">
        <constructor-arg name="outputDirectory" ref="outputFolder" />
        <constructor-arg name="useCompression" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

This should be simple, but somehow, spring throws **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No qualifying bean of type 'boolean' available.

What am i missing here?

Comment: you need to provide the type of the variable "useCompression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing component-scan and XML bean definitions.

**Approach 1:**

Use the `@Service`-annotation, but then add `@Autowired` to the constructor. Remove the definition of `FileBasedSink`-bean from XML.
If it's a constant boolean bean, then `@Value("true")` to the boolean param.
Or, as suggested by @Obi Wan - PallavJha you can declare the boolean bean somewhere in the context and use the `@Qualifier("booleanBean")`-annotation for the boolean param.

**Approach 2:**

Define the bean in XML passing the `<constructor-arg's>`, but then remove the `@Service`-annotation.

Comment: removing @service solved. I cannot use Autowired because the bean config should be external, requirement of the project. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide the type of the variable **useCompression**

```
<constructor-arg type="boolean">
   <value>true</value>
</constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean of boolean type:

```
<bean id="booleanBean" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and then use it as a reference for creating `fileSink` object, like,

```
<bean id="fileSink" class="org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.impl.file.FileBasedSink">
    <constructor-arg name="outputDirectory" ref="outputFolder" />
    <constructor-arg name="useCompression" ref="booleanBean"/>
</bean>
```